# Inserting both Script tags and Body tags into NodeJS Handlebars template

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

My question is whether or not it is possible to inject both body and script tags into a handlebars template. I have looked over the web but have only found confusing tutorials/example. To give an example, I have the following already setup and it works fine:

**layout.hbs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
        {{{ body }}}
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.hbs:**

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs  = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('hbs',hbs({extname: 'hbs'}))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

**BUT!** What I want to also achieve is something where I can also add scripts from my index.hbs into my layout.hbs in the following fashion:

**layout.hbs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {{{ script }}}  
    </head>
    <body>
        {{{ body }}}
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.hbs:**

```
<script>
    <script src="example.js" defer></script>
</script>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
```

Is this possible? and if so, what changes will I have to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, I would suggest putting the script in the layout.

As an example:

**layout.hbs:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 {{> nav }}
 {{{body}}}
 {{> footer }}
<script src="/js/file-validation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**file-validation.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
    });
}, false);
```

})();

**support.hbs**

```
 <form action="{{feedbackEmail}}"
                  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
           <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                        <input  name=name type="text" class="form-control" id="validationName" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter your name.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="validationEmail" placeholder="You@email.com" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter your email.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

This way when you put together your partials it will call the script on any .hbs file you implemented it on.

In this example it is done by the `needs-validation` class on a support form.

Comment: Your suggestion is to load the script on every page, even where it is not required. It doesn't answer the question of how to load the script only for certain views. I'm confused as to why this answer was accepted.